# How to add a text box and a column to save text in it dynamically in ASP.NET MVC 3 application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.3.1

I have to add a button which when clicked creates a new text box where I can add some text and save it in database.

For example- I click button thrice it will create 3 text boxes and 3 new columns in database to save them.

Application is in ASP.NET MVC 3 and Entity Framework 4.3.1. Is it possible to do that using EF as it maps to static classes?

Comment: It would be possible by executing stored procedures or executing inline code from Entity Framework.  I wouldn't recommend it, why would you need to do it when you have a relational database?

Comment: Are you sure you need three additional columns? Why can't you just have another joined table for all such extra information?

Comment: But even in other joined table , number of columns cannot be fixed as they  depend on number of text boxes created . OR I should create like table with say 50 columns and map new text box to a column whenever it is created ?

Comment: No, you'd have a tablei with just three columns: id, key, value. Key stands for your additionak column name, value stands for the value. Instead of three additional columns you have three rows, (key: columnA, value: something), etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
    You can achieve this by following steps:
    //View page
    1)Write a function which creates a textbox and render in div.
    Something like this:

    <input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="Add" />
    <div id="TextBoxContainer">
    //Area of textboxes
    </div>
    <br />


    $(function () {
        $("#btnAdd").bind("click", function () {
            var div = $("<div />");
            div.html(GetTextBox(""));
            $("#TextBoxContainer").append(div);
        });

    });
    function GetTextBox(value) {
        return '<input name = "TextBox" type="text" />'
    }


    //Server side code
    Write an event handler on button click which adds three columns in the database.  
This could be done either by writing stored procedure or create statement.
```